# split database output in mule

Tags: database, mule, splitter

I'm having below database output, how do i split it.

```
 [{country=United States, accountID=4410, street=12345 Green Rd, state=Colorado, name=Dale Burgers, city=Boulder, postal=80305}, {country=United Kingdom, accountID=4411, street=capthorne Avenue, state=Harrow, name=Arjun, city=london, postal=ha29eb}, {country=usa, accountID=4412, street=elden st, state=va, name=Home Foods, city=herndon, postal=20170}, {country=usa, accountID=4413, street=herndon parkway, state=va, name=Home Foods 2, city=herndon, postal=20170}, {country=usa, accountID=4414, street=van barun st, state=va, name=home foods 3, city=herndon, postal=20170}, {country=United Kingdom, accountID=4415, street=355 E Capthorne Court, Alexandra Avenue, state=Harrow, name=Barkha , city=Haarow London, postal=ha29eb}, {country=Canada, accountID=4416, street=4130 Chromoly, state=BC, name=Spawn Cycles, city=Squamish, postal=L0L0L0}, {country=Canada, accountID=4417, street=1 Yonge Street, state=BC, name=Post Spawn, city=Vancouver, postal=L1L1L1}, {country=Canada, accountID=4418, street=1 Yonge Street, state=BC, name=Post Post Spawn, city=Vancouver, postal=L2L2L2}, {country=Canada, accountID=4419, street=1 Yonge Street, state=BC, name=Post Post Post Spawn, city=Vancouver, postal=L0L0L0}]
```

i tried adding JSON to Object Transformer forming List type and Collection splitter but only first record is being passed.

```
 {country=United States, accountID=4410, street=12345 Green Rd, state=Colorado, name=Dale Burgers, city=Boulder, postal=80305}
```

Comment: @Mahesh_Loya can you please have a look ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way around is to convert the json to a java object using json to object transformer and that should provide you a collection of objects. You can then loop on this collection using foreach processor in Mule.

Hope this help.

Comment: yeah i was able to do this way.. but it was failing by using splitter component .. I'm not sure what mistake I have been doing..

Comment: I guess in that case you will need to post a sample snippet for testing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Database connector is returning values in `java.util.LinkedList` format, If you want to split the result as record by record then use For-each scope after the Database poll component.
Please find below the sample snippet:

```
 <db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="hostname" port="3306" user="mule" password="welcome1" database="schema" doc:name="MySQL Configuration"/>
    <flow name="database-47729955Flow">
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="10" timeUnit="SECONDS"/>
            <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
                <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM schema.table_name where B2B_REQUEST_TYPE='Send';]]></db:parameterized-query>
            </db:select>
        </poll>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each">
            <logger message="#['\n Database record is:'+payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <logger message="#['\nNext record']" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </foreach>
    </flow>
```

Regards,

Sreenivas B

Answer (score -1):

Database output should be List or Iterator only. But if you are getting JSON. You can achieve it in following ways

Using Dataweave which will return List-

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload
```

Using [Dataweave MEL function](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/mel-dataweave-functions#the-split-function) which will return `Iterator (SplitIterator)` -

```
<set-payload value="#[split('payload','application/json')]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

Using JSON to Object Transformer -

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.List" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
```

Hope this helps.